# Resource for backward compatibility in HTML5?

Tags: html, mobile-website

Are there resources or JS libraries to emulate HTML5 features, if the browser doesn't fully support HTML5.

I am specifically looking to target mobile web applications.

Thanks,

Sri

Comment: Your question is a bit broad. Are there HTML5 specific features you wish to emulate with javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you should give a try to [HTML5shiv](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/).

Answer (score 1):

[Modernizr](http://diveintohtml5.info/detect.html#modernizr) is a library for detecting support for HTML5 and CSS3 features.

It doesn’t do any automatic fixing itself (I don’t think so anyway...), but it’s a solid base to use for adapting your application to browsers that don’t support what you need.

Not sure how well it runs on mobile devices — JavaScript performance tends to be pretty slow on mobile.

Answer (score 0):

Most mobile browser don´t have good js support. So it´s difficult you can emulate HTML5 or anything.

Comment: Define “most”? Mobile versions of WebKit have great HTML5 support, and WebKit is pretty widely used on mobile devices that people actually use to browse the web (i.e. iPhone and Android).

Comment: Yes you are right, WebKit has good support of HTML5 and it will be better. And webkit generate most traffic in mobile web. But the rest of mobile has bad support of js and you can´t emulate any html5. Yet most of device are not webkit.
more info: http://www.quirksmode.org/mobile/

Comment: Sure — of all the mobile browsers out there, there are lots that don’t support HTML5 or indeed JavaScript. But which ones of those are regular people likely to buy and use? Phones with rubbish web support won’t get used for web browsing.

Comment: @Paul it depends of your business and target country. There are good business with old and crapy mobile browsers